# Electron - Webview must be attached to the DOM error

Tags: reactjs, webview, electron

In my Electron/React app, I have the possibility to open video content that is hosted on another web app. What I do is render a `webview` of the required page with an URL. Here is my example:

```
const App = ({ computedMatch }) => {
  const { audioMuted } = useSelector(({ window }) => window);
  const titleId = computedMatch.params.id;
  const src = `${BASE_URL}/${titleId}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const webview = document.querySelector('webview');
    if (webview) {
      webview.setAudioMuted(audioMuted);
    }
  }, [audioMuted]);

  return <webview src={src} />;
};
```

On the windows bar I have a mute button icon, pressing the mute button, updates the Redux state of the `audioMuted` to `true`. When the state is change the `useEffect` comes in action

On the first hand this solution seemed to be working, but after some testing, sometimes I receive this error:

```
error: uncaughtException: The WebView must be attached to the DOM and the dom-ready event emitted before this method can be called.
Error: The WebView must be attached to the DOM and the dom-ready event emitted before this method can be called.
```

How do I fix this error to never appear in the first place?